# ASP.NET Gridview - setting column header's css class from code behind?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, sorting, webforms

Hey guys, what I am trying to do is add a method to my gridview's sorting event to add a class to the column being sorted so the user can know if the data is being sorted ascending or descending and on what column. I am currently trying to do it through a switch statement on the sort expression to determine what column it's coming from but I am unaware of how to set the css class. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it working, turns out I was over thinking it but the task is easily accomplished via:

```
gridview.HeaderRow.Cells[0].CssClass = "sorted" + sortString;
```

Comment: Be aware that this only works for columns that were not autogenerated (I mean by using AutogenerateColumns = True (true is the default value by the way), because the autogenerated columns will not be added to the column collection.

Comment: yeah I am aware, and it isn't an autogenerated column

Answer (score 0):

You can add the styles to the gridview columns using this sample codes:

```
// Add styles to table
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridViewSample.Rows)
        {
            GridViewSample.HeaderRow.Cells[2].CssClass = "text-center";
            GridViewSample.HeaderRow.Cells[3].CssClass = "text-center";
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                row.Cells[2].CssClass = "text-center";
                row.Cells[3].CssClass = "text-center";
            }
        }
```